# Summing From Consecutive Rows

Tags: t-sql

Assume we have a table and we want to do a sum of the Expend column so that the summation only adds up values of the same Week_Name.

```
SN  Week_Name  Exp  Sum
--  ---------  ---  ---
1   Week 1     10   0
2   Week 1     20   0
3   Week 1     30   60
4   Week 2     40   0
5   Week 2     50   90
6   Week 3     10   0
```

I will assume we will need to `Order By' Week_Name, then compare the previous  Week_Name(previous row) with the current row Week_name(Current row).
If both are the same, put zero in the SUM column.

If not the same, add all expenditure, where Week_Name = Week_Name(Previous row) and place in the Sum column. The final output should look like the table above.

Any help on how to achieve this in T-SQL is highly appreciated.

Comment: What version of SQL Server... or is it Sybase?  Both use TSQL...  And what have you tried?

Comment: Don't you want to do this with reqular SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your SN=6 line is 0 rather than 10.  Do you really not want the sum for the last Week?  If having the last week total is okay, then you might want something like:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT Week_Name,SUM([Expend.]) as SumExpend
  ,MAX(SN) AS MaxSN
  FROM T
  GROUP BY Week_Name
  )
SELECT T.*,CASE WHEN T.SN = CTE.MaxSN THEN SumExpend
           ELSE 0 END AS [Sum]
FROM T
JOIN CTE on CTE.Week_Name = T.Week_Name
```

Based on the requst in the comment wanting a running total in SUM you could try this:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT Week_Name, MAX(SN) AS MaxSN
FROM T
GROUP BY Week_Name
)
SELECT T.SN, T.Week_Name,T.Exp, 
CASE WHEN T.SN = CTE.MaxSN THEN
(SELECT SUM(EXP) FROM T T2 
 WHERE T2.SN <= T.SN) ELSE 0 END AS [SUM]
FROM T
JOIN CTE ON CTE.Week_Name = T.Week_Name
ORDER BY SN
```

Comment: Certainly worked the seamlessly GiLM, and you were right about the last column. It is ok to have the last week total. However, I have a slight modification to the original table. How do I make the sum column cummulative. So that in the above example, the 3rd row would be 60, the 5th row would be 150 and the last row 160 (all on the SUM column).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was eventually able to resolve this issue, praise Jesus! If you want the exact table I gave above, you can use GilM's response below, it is perfect. If you want your table to have running Cumulatives, i.e. Rows 3 shoud have 60, Row 5, should have 150, Row 6 160 etc. Then, you can use my code below:

```
USE CAPdb 
IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.[tablebp]') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE [tablebp] 

GO
CREATE TABLE [tablebp] (
    tablebpcCol1 int PRIMARY KEY
  ,tabledatekey datetime
  ,tableweekname varchar(50)
  ,expenditure1 numeric
  ,expenditure_Cummulative numeric
)   

INSERT INTO [tablebp](tablebpcCol1,tabledatekey,tableweekname,expenditure1,expenditure_Cummulative)
SELECT b.s_tablekey,d.PK_Date,d.Week_Name,
SUM(b.s_expenditure1) AS s_expenditure1,
SUM(b.s_expenditure1) + COALESCE((SELECT SUM(s_expenditure1)
    FROM source_table bs JOIN dbo.Time dd ON bs.[DATE Key] = dd.[PK_Date]
    WHERE dd.PK_Date < d.PK_Date),0)
FROM source_table b
INNER JOIN dbo.Time d ON b.[Date key] = d.PK_Date 
GROUP BY d.[PK_Date],d.Week_Name,b.s_tablekey,b.s_expenditure1
ORDER BY d.[PK_Date]

;WITH CTE AS ( 
   SELECT tableweekname
   ,Max(expenditure_Cummulative) AS Week_expenditure_Cummulative
   ,MAX(tablebpcCol1) AS MaxSN 
FROM [tablebp] 
GROUP BY tableweekname 
) 
SELECT [tablebp].*
,CASE WHEN [tablebp].tablebpcCol1 = CTE.MaxSN THEN Week_expenditure_Cummulative
       ELSE 0 END AS [RunWeeklySum]
FROM [tablebp]
JOIN CTE on CTE.tableweekname = [tablebp].tableweekname
```